# Gradle: Make task from custom plugin run first

Tags: plugins, groovy, gradle

I have a custom gradle plugin, say myPlugin, with a task, say myTask, that has to validate and create a file before the build starts. How do I make sure that gradle runs myTask before any other task from any other plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a task for that. You can use a hook such as `project.gradle.buildStarted { ... }`.

Comment: I tried what you suggested in root project's build.gradle but I do not see it being invoked. Can you show an example as how can I trigger buildStarted for root project in a multi module build?